# Convert powerpoint to flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, powerpoint

How hard is it to import a powerpoint presentation into flash. It would be perfect for me if the output would look like this: every powerpoint slide becomes a movieclip or a .swf file. I don't have any animations and sounds, its just text and images. I know i could save the slides to png but its very bad idea using bitmaps for text in flash. I also cant use programs like slideshare, because they add their own navigation bars and i cant use them offline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/)'s Impress has a Powerpoint import, and Flash export function. I have no idea how it will work for your case, but give it a shot before you start exporting manually.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [FlashPoint PowerPoint to flash converter](http://www.flashdemo.net), it supports PowerPoint 2003 and 2007, the navigation bar can be hided based on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  openOffice or powerpoint 2007 (which has in-built xps support) for exporting your presentations into pdf's and then use [pdf2swf](http://www.swftools.org) for converting pdf into swfs.

Answer (score 2):

There are [6 ways to convert PowerPoint to flash](http://www.sameshow.com/other/6-ways-convert-powerpoint-to-flash.html#110), maybe it helps.

Comment: This is just an ad for one of their products (which they list as the first method).

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a number of converters on the open market. I use [Articulate Presenter](http://www.articulate.com/products/presenter.php), which is quite good.

Comment: thanks but this one also has its own navigation bar ect. i dont need this extra stuff.