# Convert Powerpoint to Flash in Linux

Tags: powerpoint, flv

I'm looking to convert PPT and PPTX files to Flash (or flv) files in an automated fashion in Linux - So I need a command-line utility.

Are there any available options out there for me? (I haven't found any so far).

I was also looking for a Flash player to play ppt/pptx files as an alternative (similar to what slideshare provides) - does anyone know of any other than [openslide](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openslide/)?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Related question here: [Convert powerpoint to flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992246/convert-powerpoint-to-flash)

Summary of answers: you should probably use OpenOffice to do it.

To do it from the command-line, it looks like you should probably use PyODConverter http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/pyodconverter

Answer (score 0):

OpenOffice generates a very poor SWF version. It should generate a back/foward button at least.